# Sync element to a child on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My Shema database is

User Table

```
    id
    login
    parent
```

Sign Table

```
    id
    name
    user_id (Sign owner)
```

Pivot table user_sign

```
    id
    user_id
    sign_id
```

My User model contain

```
    public function signs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sign', 'user_sign');
    }


    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'parent');
    }

    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'parent', 'user_id');
    }
```

And my Sign model contain

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_sign')->select(['users.id','name']);
    }
```

A parent user can attach / sync Sign to a child user via this route (he send sign_id and child_id)

```
    Route::put('sign/share', 'SignController@share')
```

To do this action, in my controller i must check :
- if Owner of sign_id is $user_id
- If child_id is child of $user_id

And after that, i do my attach / sync.

Now, in my controller i have :

```
public function share(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->input('user_id');
    $sign = Sign::where('user_id', $userId)->find($id);

    if(!$sign){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'FAIL'], 404);
    }
}
```

But I completely blocked after this... It's possible to check and attach in one line ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as syncing/attaching you can use this sytanx

```
$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

As given in [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

You can do the both checks in the condition of IF and assign in case of true, thats how your controller will look like finally.

```
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        $userId = $request->input('user_id');
        $signId = $request->input('sign_id');
        $childId = $request->input('child_id');            
        if (Sign::find($singId)->user_id == $userId && User::find($userId)->child_id == $childId) 
        {

           //Attach the sign to child user
           User::find($childId)->signs()->attach($signId);

        }
        else 
        {

              return response()->json(['message'=>'FAIL'], 404);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. user_id is passed from my oauth server.

Comment: My pb isn't to do the sync but how check if Owner of sign_id is $user_id and If child_id is child of $user_id. Thanks